# When we are trying to delete kafka topic it is just showing like "marked for deletion"

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

> ERROR Error while renaming dir for tes78686-0 in log dir
>   E:\tmp\kafka-logs (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
>   java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: E:\tmp\kafka-logs\tes78686-0 ->
>   E:\tmp\kafka-logs\tes78686-0.c2a2030cbfbb49229d40575b29b2bb3a-delete
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:387)

I am using Windows. First, I tried to delete the kafka topic. But it's showing as
topicname `topic marked for deletion` but it is not deleting the same. Kafka is shutting down and it is showing an error as shown above.

Comment: can u resolve this error

Comment: How did you delete the kafka topic?

Comment: Kafka is not extensively tested on windows... File permission issues are probably the most common error

Comment: @MadhuBhat     I have deleted using the command .\bin\windows\kafka-topics.bat -zookeeper localhost:2181 -topic 'topicname' -delete   .I tried with the Adding ACL for delete permission  also .\bin\windows\kafka-acls.bat --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:admin --operation All --group groupname  --topic topicname

Comment: **@cricket_007**  yes  i think file permissions issues are the most commonly prone error but for only deleting topics it is raising this issue `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: E:\tmp\kafka-logs\tes78686-0 -> E:\tmp\kafka-logs\tes78686-0.ab3b646f7ed449f1b2ae1a46a78073a7-delete
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)`

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you resolve it finally? @chundivamsikrishna